# Why does using Option::map to Box::new a trait object not work?

Tags: rust, trait-objects

```rust
trait FooTrait {}

struct FooStruct;

impl FooTrait for FooStruct {}

fn main() {
    let maybe_struct: Option<dyn FooStruct> = None;

    //  Does not compile
    let maybe_trait: Option<Box<dyn FooTrait>> = maybe_struct.map(Box::new);

    // Compiles fine
    let maybe_trait: Option<Box<dyn FooTrait>> = match maybe_struct {
        Some(s) => Some(Box::new(s)),
        None => None,
    };
}
```

```
error[E0404]: expected trait, found struct `FooStruct`
 --> src/main.rs:9:34
  |
9 |     let maybe_struct: Option<dyn FooStruct> = None;
  |                                  ^^^^^^^^^ not a trait
```

Rustc 1.23.0. Why doesn't the first approach compile? Am I missing something obvious, or... huh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Box::new` only works with sized types; that is, it takes a value of a sized type `T` and returns `Box<T>`.  In certain places a `Box<T>` can be [coerced](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html) into a `Box<U>` (if [`T: Unsize<U>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-CoerceUnsized%3CBox%3CU%3E%3E)).

Such coercion does not happen in `.map(Box::new)`, but does in `Some(Box::new(s))`; the latter is basically the same as `Some(Box::new(s) as Box<FooTrait>)`.

You could create (in nightly) your own box constructor that returns boxes of unsized types like this:

```
#![feature(unsize)]

fn box_new_unsized<T, U>(v: T) -> Box<U>
where
    T: ::std::marker::Unsize<U>,
    U: ?Sized,
{
    Box::<T>::new(v)
}
```

and use it like `.map(box_new_unsized)`.  See [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9632f5644444c3f969f3818e63030e67&version=nightly).

Comment: Aha, I was missing the `as Box<FooTrait>` implicitly happenning behind the scenes, and the (in retrospect obvious) fact that the `as` is *NOT* a no-op, creating a trait object is not just a play with type ascriptions, but an actual operation. If I want to use `.map`, I can explicitily `let maybe_trait = maybe_struct.map(|x| Box::new(x) as Box<FooTrait>);`. I'll yet have to fully digest coerctions, `Unsize` and friends. Thanks.

Comment: @TomášDvořák Btw: you can often omit the target type in `as`-expressions like this: `|x| Box::new(x) as _`.

Comment: This `as Box<FooTrait>` syntax also help me as well with a fairly different context than the problem posed here.