# Why does creating a collection of const pointers work with `for val in a.iter()` but not `a.iter().map(|val| val)`?

Tags: rust

This code works:

```
let mut b: Vec<*const SimpleStruct> = Vec::with_capacity(a.len());
for val in a.iter() {
    b.push(val);
}
```

This code does not work:

```
let b: Vec<*const SimpleStruct> = a.iter().map(|val| val).collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f31e3e07ecb1c82204a85e914bdd8e27)

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push `&SimpleStruct` to a `Vec<*const SimpleStruct>`, Rust knows that it can coerce the reference into a pointer. However, when you `collect` it, Rust is trying to coerce a `Vec<&SimpleStruct>` to a `Vec<*const SimpleStruct>`, which it can't do, so you should be more explicit:

```rust
let b: Vec<*const SimpleStruct> = a.iter().map(|val| val as *const SimpleStruct).collect();
```

or

```rust
let b: Vec<*const SimpleStruct> = a.iter().map(|val| -> *const SimpleStruct { val }).collect();
```

Comment: See also [Use Option::map to Box::new a trait object does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48864045/155423); [Why are iterator items which are references not cast to a trait object reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520085/155423).

Comment: `let b: Vec<_> = ...` would be both shorter, less redundant, and more idiomatic.